# Automatically fill command line input of variable size

Tags: python, shell, unix, input

I have a Python script which asks for some arguments when running (using `raw_input`). I'd like to be able to run this script and feed it with some inputs (basically, I need to alternate between 2 values as long as it needs input).

I know how to feed it with a single value using the *yes* program but I don't know how to obtain a sequence like *a b a b a b*

What's the simplest way ?

Answer (score 6):

```
yes $'a\nb' | script.py
```

Uses bash's [`$'...'` syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) for string literals which contain escape sequences. Alternatively:

```
while true; do echo a; echo b; done | script.py
```